# Best way to do HTTP Concurrency Test?

Tags: unit-testing, http, testing, concurrency

I php application that is hosted on Apache Server and now I want to do some concurrency test on it so that I know that one instance of apache server can take how many concurrent http request and how that number of concurrent http request would increase in relation to

- Increasing number of thread
- Increasing number of server instances

What would be best approach for doing this kind of concurrency testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a program called [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) which is just what you need. If you are on Fedora or a RedHat-based Linux distribution, you'll find it in the `httpd-tools` package.